# MPI client server communication

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, client-server, mpi

I have one main PC and 3 other client PC that I am trying to send message to. All of them are in the same network, and I like to send a message to them, one by one, so that they do something simple like printing and sending a success msg to the main computer (server). I am new to MPI, so I don't know how to make this connections? How does the client computers listen to the msg from the server? I have written a program that separates the functions of clients and server. If it is the client it would connect to that with the specified port number and ip address and send a msg to the client. However when I try to do `MPI_Open_port(info, port1);` it gives me an error that if fails to open the port. Should I have this program on all client computers? If someone can give a general overview of how it works I would appreciate it.

Comment: Try running the associated test from the MPICH test suite to verify the MS-MPI is working properly on your machine

Comment: Thanks Jeff for your suggestion, What I like to know is that if it is even possible to do something like a TCP connection between the two computers in the network where one of them will be the master and the other one, client. Or should I switch to something like winsock. What I will do is simply sending commands to do something on the client side and then the clients will return a flag if they have successfully finished the job.